# How to compute the average of a column in a CSV file?

Tags: linux, bash

I would like to compute the average of a certain column in a CSV file with column separator ";". How can I do this with Linux command line tools such as awk?

Example:

```
 foo;1;test
 bar;3;hello
```

Average of column `2` is `2`.

Comment: @Raze2dust I would guess due to the ease with which this question can be answered with a quick search on your favorite search engine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A quick search for "[bash average](http://www.bing.com/search?q=bash%20average)" turned up as the first result: [Compute simple average using AWK](http://www.unixcl.com/2008/03/compute-simple-average-using-awk.html)

Tidied up for your use case, it's:

```
$ awk -F';' '{sum+=$2; ++n} END { print "Avg: "sum"/"n"="sum/n }' < /tmp/yourdata
Avg: 4/2=2
```

Answer (score 2):

Lets think, you have csv file 1.csv.
command should look like this:

```
   cat 1.txt | awk -F';' '{sum+=$2} END {print sum/NR}'
```